# Solr update with empty array list for multivalued field failing with solrj v4.3.1

Tags: solr, solrj

I want to update a Solr Document's multivalued field. I am trying with this

```
    SolrInputDocument input = new SolrInputDocument();
    input.setField("id","14378477");
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> hash = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
    hash.put("set", new ArrayList<String>());
    System.out.println(hash);
    input.setField("field_name",hash);

    client.add(input);
```

It is giving me error that document missing required field 'required_field'. But at the same time if I am trying this one

```
    SolrInputDocument input = new SolrInputDocument();
    input.setField("id","14378477");
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> hash = new 
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
    hash.put("set", null);
    System.out.println(hash);
    input.setField("field_name",hash);
    client.add(input);
```

It is giving me correct output by removing "field_name" field from the Solr Document. Can anybody please let me know what to do use this? I want to use the above syntax.

Comment: same thing is working in Solrj v6.6.0

Comment: Then it sounds like a bug in SolrJ 4.3.1 - have you checked the changelog between those versions or tried using a more recent version than 4.3.1 to see if the bug has been fixed there (while no other incompatibilities have been introduced)?

Comment: Hi, I cannot use higher version because I am deserializing the Document Object which is serialized in 4.3.1. The serialUUID is changed